# Crap audio interface sound and I can't find out the problem

Tags: guitar, recording, mixing

I've bought an Audio Interface (Line 6 Studio UX2) some years ago and I've always connected from my guitar to my iMac. I usually recorded metal/metalcore riff, tried different VST plugins (Guitar Rig, Amplitube, Pod Farm, TSE505 ) but I've never heard a CLEAR sound from my mac cables. The maximum acceptable result is during "breakdown" steps but if I need to clear the sound for riffs it become crappy. I hear like if middle frequency are very ugly and never warm, similar to phone call sensation, far sound.
I've updated the audio interface drivers.

My Mac RAM : 4 GB
My Mac OS: Mavericks 
Sometimes it's hard for it to manage the project but it works anyway. Sometimes I have a few latency but if I switch the Audio interface from the settings it keep working well (it seems)

My Guitar: Jackson Dinky (Jackson pickups) Made in India
Floyd Rose, Ernie Ball Strings

Audio Interface: Line 6 Studio UX 2

Jackson Dinky -> Line 6 Studio UX 2 (Instrument) -> iMac USB (Reaper)

An example (maybe not the ugliest one I recorded): 
http://justtest.altervista.org/pr/metal.mp3

Thanks for help!

P.S. Maybe it's me that overestimate audio interface. All the stuff I hear on youtube are much more better to listen than my stuff. My sounds are boring

Comment: Can you post the dry direct output of you guitar recorded through the interface so we can hear if there's a problem? The clip you posted doesn't sound horrible, I can't say that there is a "problem" per se. If the interface provides an acceptable dry guitar signal, you should just keep tweaking your amp sim settings and mix.

Comment: what do you mean for "dry direct output"? takes with no effects ?

Comment: Yes, no effects, not even the amp sim. Btw I feel the main problem with it is the lack (?) of bass guitar and bad drum sound. Guitars sound way better when supported by bass.

Comment: Ah ok. The bass is a MIDI path performed by a Kontakt Library plugin and the drummer is made by Superior Drummer. Should I wide up 20 Hz - 100 Hz Bass frequencies? I tried to increase Bass Level but I heard Bass and Guitar like separated. I guessed that should be wide and transparent at the same time. Shouldn't it?

Comment: First of all, the guitars sound acceptable. I would prefer much less gain, it would make it clearer, but it's a preference not a rule.

Secondly, I can't hear *any* bass guitar. So I can't really comment. The first thing to do should be to add some volume. Then we can discuss the tone.

Thirdly, drums, especially the cymballs, sound very unrealistic. If you wrote them yourself, I'd suggest changing the velocities to add more life. I checked some online demos and Superior Drummer 2.0 seems to sound fine normally.

Comment: I usually set Gain > 50% to "fill" the sound. I could fix adding more volume than gain? 
(For the bass and drum thanks a lot. I'm just a guitarist and miss a lot of drum/bass concepts)

Comment: First, listen to your dry guitar signal (without any FX or amp). If it's already somewhat distorted, lower your input gain on the interface (or your guitar's volume knob if the interface doesn't have one). When you get a clear sound that way, start experimenting with your amp sim settings. There are no hard and fast rules but I can tell with confidence that presets almost always suck.

Comment: Gain > 50% doesn't mean anything by itself, every amp model has different amount of gain. for reference, I use Amplitube's ENGL model in about 10-15% for classic metal (with poweramp "volume" at 100%) and at about 35-45% for newer stuff (poweramp at <60%).

Comment: Of course it also depends on my guitar's pickup output level and its setup (low/high). There are just too many variables and different tastes. Again, to me, your guitars sound acceptable for the genre.

Comment: Do you think that record from Condensator microphone my Line 6 Spider IV 15 watt or Marshall 100 watt combo should be a solution to not become crazy with vst plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a Passive Direct Box?

http://www.digiflexcables.com/2/en/products.htm

Like the first one in the list: DPDI Direct Box!

It reduces unwanted buzz sounds making the sound clearer. That is the one I use for my music projects. I plug it to either my guitars, synthetizers or other equipment!